# Getting the label of an associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I have the following array (for exemple) :

```
[{id: 1, name: name1},
{id: 2, name: name2},
...]
```

I want to get (as a string) the labels of the array. 
So i want :

```
string1 = "id";
string2 = "name";
```

Is it possible ?

I guess another option would be to define string1 and string2 BEFORE initializing the array, and using string1 and string2 as label so I can use them separatly later, but that's not really what i'm looking for.

Comment: `Object.keys(obj)`

Comment: `[{id: 1, name: name1},
{id: 2, name: name2}].forEach(function(item){ console.log(Object.keys(item)); })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply get the keys of first object in the array

```
Object.keys(obj[0])
```

This will give you an array `["id", "name"]`